# Facebook debugger shows only 2 likes even tho there are 40+ likes on my facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been browsing through a lot of questions and I am not sure if I already got my answer. I've created a new website and also created a facebook page for it. A few days ago I also integrated the ogtags into my websites header.

My facebook page got around 40 likes / shares. When I enter my website into the facebook sharing debugger it shows only "2 likes/shares". What tag am I missing to include my page likes into my website?

I am using these tags:

```
og:title
og:description
og:image
og:url
og:type
```

The debugger also tells me to use `fb:app_id`, which I don't have. Would this solve my issue? Is it even possible to link my page to my website?

Comment: Your Facebook page and your website are two completely different things

Comment: Ouch, I see...I thought you could tell facebook that they belong to each other. That means if I want to collect likes for my website, I need to integrate a like button on my website OR let people share / like the direct link of my website, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. (Although, sharing will not create a like - but the counter value you get is a combination of likes and shares.) But please be aware that you are not allowed to gate content behind a forced like, or promise them any other reward for liking or sharing.